Why my object does not display applied color?
I am new to Blender and just learn from tutorials. However I can't figure out why my object does not show any colour that I applied, its just plain white.
I followed these two tutorials multiple times and in both cases I cannot get this effect, when the "exploding" thing has colour. In first case my whole torus object is just black and in second one it's plain white.
I did each of this tutorials multiple times and can't figure out what I'm missing or doing wrong. I guess it's something in my shader? I would appreciate any tips soooo much!
Tutorial 01
Tutorial 02
This is the link to the files if anyone would be so kind...




when I was new to blender, I often forgot to switch to the material/render view to see the changes.

Unfortunately that is not the case :(

the Mix Color output that you use as factor in the Mix Shader is completely black, so it will only show the first Principled BSDF that plugged into the mix, and this is a white one, thus the white color. What were you exactly trying to do with this setup?

Torus has Weight Paint and the idea was that the first Principled BSDF is for the base and the second one is the colour for this "exploding" element and should be the same as the one that is in 2nd Principled BSDF

Your Ambient Occlusion node doesn't do anything, it is plain white. So only the first (white) material is selected. It looks like you just need to enable Ambient Occlusion in the Render tab.


That's it! Thank you sooooo much! Now it works perfectly, I'm so relieved, thanks again! Have a great day :)
